# how to add pagination in a page in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, pagination

Im deeply sorry for this rookie question. I cannot find a suitable tutorial for this.

My theme consists only:

- index.php
- footer.php
- header.php
- single.php

What I want to accomplish is to create a page that displays 15 recent posts from a particular category with pagination

Below code displays the 15 recent posts from cars category.

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php
/*
Template Name: CARS
*/
?>

<?php query_posts('category_name=cars&showposts=15'); ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
          <?php the_content(); ?>  
          </a>  </li>
        <?php endwhile; ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I created cars.php and paste the code; I then used it as a template on a Wordpress Page.
this displays 15 recent posts.

Where/how can I place a numbered pagination instead of (next/previous) hyperlinks in a page?

Thanks.